# Post photo to Tumblr with AS3 (Error #2101 decode())

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, tumblr

I'm trying to post a photo to Tumblr.com from Flash but it results in an error #2101

> Error #2101: The String passed to
>   URLVariables.decode() must be a
>   URL-encoded query string containing
>   name/value pairs

This is the code I'm using: ( ActionScript3 )

```
import com.adobe.images.PNGEncoder;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
//
var myLoader:URLLoader;
myLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
//
var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
urlVars.email = "***@*****.de";
urlVars.password = "*****";
//
urlVars.type = "photo";
//
var b:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mc.width,mc.height,true);
b.draw(mc);
var png:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(b);
//
urlVars.data = png;
//
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.tumblr.com/api/write");
//
urlRequest.contentType = "application/octet-stream";
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlRequest.data = urlVars;
myLoader.load(urlRequest)
```

Any ideas very welcome.

Thanks
Bob

Comment: Can it be that the error is caused by the return value you receive from Tumblr?  urlVars.decode() is not called explicitly in your script, so it might be an automatic decoding of the response from the server.  Perhaps the script works if you omit settings `myLoader.dataFormat`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried it but the error still comes up.

Comment: I've tested the code up until the `myLoader.load(urlRequest)`. urlVars is created correctly, all data is urlencoded, and everything looks fine.  It **has** to be the response from Tumblr that causes the problem.  What code do you use to process it?

Comment: I created a test account here: http://ffphotopost.tumblr.com/ and here is the complete code i'm using: http://pastebin.com/0u2H7LXT  I'm complete new to this API thing - so can you please explain me what you mean by "What code do you use to process it?" Thanks for helping me on this!

Comment: I was talking about the complete handler, but it seems you haven't really implemented one yet.  I tried your code, but I can't seem to get this to run at all, because tumblr's crossdomain.xml doesn't allow access from outside tumblr - so unless there is some way I can upload my Test-SWF to your account, I won't be able to help you. Sorry.

Comment: Oh that crossdomain.xml problem is new to me. Thanks for letting me know. Is there a way to post from my website to Tumblr? How the AIR apps and others do it?

Comment: Curiously: The posts I sent seem to have done something, unless you did some testing yourself - there are a number of empty posts on the page now.  You can most probably send posts by using a PHP proxy. See this example: http://xmlrpcflash.mattism.com/proxy_info.php

Comment: BTW I sent the posts to ffphotopost.tumblr.com/api/write - maybe that will help to get you on your way.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll use a php proxy to post now. cheers